# jQuery if input value is 1 and input is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, if-statement

Check the inputs, if value is 1 and is checked, set span color to green, if not, set to red.
I know that I am not selecting the span properly either, I can't figure out how I should do that.

**HTML**

```
<input type="radio"name="rate" value="1" CHECKED>
<span class="radioLabel">Yes</span>

<input type="radio" name="rate" value="0">
<span class="radioLabel">No</span>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.ratingInput input')
    .each(function() {
        if($(this).val() == ('1') && $(this).is(':selected'))
        {
            $(this + ('span')).css('border','1px solid green');
        } else {
            $(this + ('span')).css('border','1px solid red');
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/UL3Cn/

few things were incorrect: `:)`

- closing braces `})`
- instead of selectd use `checked` : http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/
- use `.next` for span

rest should fit the need `:)`

**code**

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
      $('.ratingInput input').each(function () {
          if ($(this).val() == ('1') && $(this).is(':checked')) {
              $(this).next('span').css('border', '1px solid green');
          } else {
              $(this).next('span').css('border', '1px solid red');
          }
      });
  });
```

Comment: thank you for such a complete answer, this is great!

Comment: @TheEks Glad it helped you `:)` see you around!

Answer (score 2):

This will do what you want

```
$('input')
    .each(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == ('1') && $(this).is(':checked')) {
        $(this).next('span').css('border', '1px solid green');
    } else {
        $(this).next('span').css('border', '1px solid red');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$(this).next('span').css('border','1px solid green');
```

---

<kbd>[**fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/M8Lhz/)</kbd>

```
$('input:checked[value="1"]').next('span').css('border', '1px solid green');
$('input[value!="1"]').not(':checked').next('span').css('border', '1px solid red');
```

---

<kbd>[**fiddle Demo with classes**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/M8Lhz/)</kbd>